# Is it possbile to modify attributes that were called

Tags: python, class, methods, getattr

I'm not entirely sure what I'm trying to ask is possible at all. I've been staring at this for a while and haven't had much luck with search engines. The exact code is a little too large to fit so I'm hoping I can get my point across with this.

I have this class setup as below. calling `stack.echo('test', special=True)` operates exactly like I want it too.

calling `stack.echo.fail('test', special=True)`, does not. I know that it is handling the echo attribute, and then the function I'm returning has no .fail attribute. What i'd like instead is for stack.echo.fail to work just the same, but the name would be `echo.fail`.

As the attributes build I'd like it to keep going. ex: If I do `stack.echo.fail.pass('test', special=True)`, I'd like the name to be `echo.fail.pass`

Is it possible to handle this the way I'd like to, and if so where should I start looking. I fear that it is possible but outside the scope of my current skill level, I've only been using python for 6 months or so.

also worth noting in my actual project the printer method equivalent needs to return an object that stores data from the function. I have that setup, but just so you're aware it does need to return an object as well.

If you're curious about my reason for wanting this, I don't really have one aside from I just want my program to work this way.

```
class printer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __getattr__(self, attr: str):

        def unknown_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.printer(attr, *args, **kwargs)
        return unknown_wrapper

    def printer(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Name:{name}\nArguments:{args}\nKeys:{kwargs}')

stack = printer()
stack.echo('test', special=True)
stack.echo.fail('test', special=True)
```

This is my output:

```
Name:echo
Arguments:('test',)
Keys:{'special': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/volitank/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    stack.echo.fail('test', special=True)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fail'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it before I got any answers so I'm going to post my solution in case anyone else is looking for something similar.

I have a tuple to check against because there is a list of things i want to stay like.this, while everything else should be subbed out into arguments like the last output. I'm sure this is going to have plenty of bugs in the future, but I'm happy with it's functionality for now

```
DOT_TUPLE = ('echo.fail', 'echo.mpass')

class printer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(self.list) >1:
            name =''
            for i in self.list:
                name = name.lstrip('.')+'.'+i
            if name not in DOT_TUPLE:
                name = self.list.pop(0)
                args = tuple(self.list)+args
        else:
            name = self.list[0]
        self.list.clear()
        self.printer(name, *args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr: str):
        self.list.append(attr)
        return self

    def printer(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{name} {args} {kwargs}')

stack = printer()
stack.echo('test', special=True)
stack.echo.fail('test', special=True)
stack.echo.mpass()
stack.anything.at.all()
```

Output of this was:

```
echo ('test',) {'special': True}
echo.fail ('test',) {'special': True}
echo.mpass () {}
anything ('at', 'all') {}
```